# Should I run email dispatching code via Sveltekit endpoints, Netlify functions or Netlify Edge?

Tags: svelte, serverless, netlify, sveltekit, netlify-function

I have an order page for which I handle form submission via a POST RequestHandler in a SvelteKit endpoint ([code example](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-post-put-patch-delete)). This endpoint is, so far, mostly in charge of persisting the submitted data via the Sanity Client API.

Now, I want to dispatch email confirmations (Sendgrid in my case) after the data gets persisted. I'm having a hard time deciding whether I should do that directly in the SvelteKit endpoint, or in a Netlify function.

While answering the original question (in title), please also help me clarify:

- whether `@sveltejs/adapter-netlify` actually runs SvelteKit endpoints  using Netlify functions by default (and, if so, why I can't list them with `netlify functions:list` or execute them with `netlify functions:invoke endpoint`)
- which scenario might be a better fit for the one or the other
- whether the newer type of [Netlify Edge](https://www.netlify.com/products/edge/) functions specifically fit this use case or not.

Thanks a lot!